# Session Variable doesnot persist value in next request in Spring MVC controller

Tags: json, spring, session, spring-mvc

I have application wide single controller.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value="services")
@ResponseBody
mwpWebServices(@RequestBody String data, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws JSONException, UnknownHostException, MongoException

{
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    ......

    String method = jsonObj.getString("method");

    ....

    if(method.equals("login"))
    {
        someClassObj.login(params);//which stores some value in session variable "somevar"
    }

    if(method.equals("other"))
    {
        System.out.println(session.getAttributes("somevar"));//coming null
    }
}
```

now "data" will recieve JSON String 
and I will parse in into JSONObject that will look like 
{"method":"login","action":"Auth","params":"Some data"}

now when method is login

i call some method of another class to which I pass session object which store some value in session

but when next time when request comes, session varible doesn't persist value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpSession of requires the client i.e. Browser to store the session id in cookie.
So my browser's cookie was off, that's why each request was bringing new session id

Comment: mistakenly, I forgot to on my browser's cookie

Answer (score 0):

```
if(method.equals("login"))
    {
        someClassObj.login(params);
        //which stores some value in session variable "somevar"
    }
```

How can it store 'some value in session variable "somevar"' if you don't pass the Session or Request object in?

Comment: @Sean i'm passing session to login function .forgot to mention it here..sorry

Comment: @Sean but then too session variable coming null i mean to say

Comment: @Ravi OK, sounds like you get a new session with each request. Does your client store / send cookies or otherwise keep track of the session?

Comment: @Sean..No what we do is that we send session ID to client first time and client sends that ID each time it makes request during session

Comment: @Ravi OK, and how do you associate that ID with a session? jSessionId= URLs?

Comment: @Sean when user logins we get session.getId() and store in session var and we send this Id to client in the response and client sends this Id in the JSON string in subsequent requests which we will parse and check against the Id we stored in session variable

Comment: @Ravi *check against the Id we stored in session variable* how? if you have a new session for every request, how could you ever match the incoming ID? One of us is misunderstanding something here ...

Comment: @Sean ok..I think I need fresh perspective. Can you guide me how best I can use HttpRequest and session in Spring MVC. Only requirement is that I want to store some value for the first time and this value I will check for each request until user logs-out. Sorry If I annoying you..

Comment: @Ravi I'll try to answer in a few hours. Gotta go home now :-)